# Overriding the PageModel() constructer for setting up default properties (Razor Pages)

Tags: c#, razor, razor-pages

I am new to Razor Pages and looking for the best way to solve my problem.

Say I have an IndexModel class, that has some properties that rely on a DB context that is injected via the Constructer, such as a drop down list of Membership Levels, that comes directly from a table...

My question is what is the best way to handle populating this drop down list that I have for ALL requests that results in the same page being reloaded / returned. I know that I can put logic in OnGet to set up the list, the problem arises if say in OnPost, ModelState.IsValid is false, and so the page is returned with Page(). If I don't explicitly reinitialize the select list in OnPost, then I get a null reference exception, which is fair enough. Rewriting the code in the OnPost method goes against DRY principles, so I looked to writing a ConfirgureProperties() method in the class when needed.

Then by testing, I found that I can just set up a constructer that will take care of populating properties for me whenever they are needed, and I don't have to call anything else. Even when DI is involved, the injection is resolved at the top of the constructer, then I can use the context to do what I need for the other properties later in the constructer. I have seen no examples of this anywhere online, I only ever see people using constructers in page models that handle DI EXCLUSIVELY.

Is there a reason I SHOULD NOT be doing this, like bad coding practice or something, or is it ok for me to use page model constructers in this way?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You only need to make the database call to repopulate the options in `OnPost` if ModelState is invalid. Chances are, if you have set up your validation correctly, that 99% of the time validation errors will be caught on the client and you won't need to repopulate the options.

Obtaining data from a database is costly, and you should only do it when necessary. So using the constructor approach contravenes this principal.

It's not like you are saving a lot of code either. Your `ConfigureProperties` method will only be called in two places in the PageModel.